# reatining selection of drodown list which is inside a user control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, viewstate

I have seen two few other posts related to this but I have doubts related to my code. So kindly bear with me.

I have user control which has a text boa and a drop down list and few custom validators.
The user control is added dynamically through a code.

I am using follwoing code to load the dropdownlist inside user control itself

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        ddl_RRC.DataSource = dicRC_Desc;
        ddl_RRC.DataTextField = "value";
        ddl_RRC.DataValueField = "key";
        ddl_RRC.DataBind();

        txtRC.Text = Request.Form[txtRC.UniqueID];   //To retain the value of text box         
    }
```

I am adding the user control dynamically on Page_Init

```
 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GetPostBackControl(this) == "btnNewRow")
        {
            custControlCountID++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < custControlCountID; i++)
        {
            RejRow customControl = (RejRow)LoadControl("~/RejRow.ascx");
            customControl.ID = "rejRow" + i;
            divHolder.Controls.Add(customControl);
        }
    }
```

Viewstate is enabled for both the text box and drop down list.
As I am using the same ID while adding the controls in Page_Init, why the controls are not getting the values from viewstate?

Comment: Where is the `custControlCountID` variable declared, does it store the value in `ViewState`?

Comment: `custControlCountID` is a private static variable of `_Default` class

Comment: Static variables are application wide and shared across all users. So every user that would visit this page would share the same variable. Remove it immediately and replace it with a property that uses a `ViewState` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I have implemented this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only problem is that you have you're  databinding the `DropDownList` on every postback from `Page_Load`. Just check the `IsPostback`-property, e.g.:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {     
        ddl_RRC.DataSource = dicRC_Desc;
        ddl_RRC.DataTextField = "value";
        ddl_RRC.DataValueField = "key";
        ddl_RRC.DataBind();
    }

    txtRC.Text = Request.Form[txtRC.UniqueID];   //To retain the value of text box         
}
```

However, i'm not sure why you need to set the `TextBox.Text` property from the form-fields since it should store it's `Text` also in `ViewState`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right about the form-fields for viewstate. I added it erlier because I guess viewstae was set to false for my user control. And now its not needed. However for the dropdownlist, when I am using if(!postback), on clicking the button to add new row the selection is retained for previous control, but the new controls are not even getting the values. You see as it needs to be populated at page load and through a button it is always postback so this code gets executed only for the first control when entire form loads for the first time

Comment: @nishantv: You should handle the `btnNewRow-click` event to create the new control instead of using `Page_Init`. I think you have misunderstood how you should (re)create dynamic controls. Create them in the event which triggered it, but **recreate** them in `Page_Init`(or `Page_Load` th the latest). You should databind it when you create it first.

Comment: Even if I seperate the code from Page_Init for creating the control, the problem persists. The problem is loading the drop down list at Page_Load of user control. As the button click event is involved, there is always a postback. If I load the ddl with `if(!postback)` the controls are not loaded at all. If i don't use `if(!postback)` the ddl is reloaded and selection is lost.